# Get the ipaddress of windows phone mango device

Tags: windows-phone-7

In the deviceextendedproperties class there is no way to get the ip address of thedevice.
refer : [deviceextendedproperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).
Please will you tell me how to get this.

Comment: Hit a server you own with a specified ID?

Answer (score 1):

To get the IP address, do a remote lookup on a site like http://www.whatsmyip.org/

There's no API for this, and neither should there be.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API currently in the WP7 for knowing Ip address.
But other network properties can be [obtained are describe in this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation%28v=VS.92%29.aspx